# Caps Lock as a Control (Ctrl) key though the shell command

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, capslock

I'm using an Awesome WM, so the default settings provider doesn't work for me.

Is there a simple shell way to make the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key code instead?

Comment: You do realize Ubuntu 17.04 reached EOL back in January (2017-April + 9 months), and is now off-topic on this site (due EOL status).  Your system has no meltdown, spectre or other fixes due EOL status.  You should upgrade to 17.10 (which itself reaches EOL later this month), then be ready to jump to 18.04 very fast.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I've got 17.10 on my home machine and the problem is actual for it too.

Comment: Ubuntu Artful (17.10) will go EOL and loose support [in 9 days](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2018-July/000232.html) too. Your question is still on topic until then but it may be more worthwhile for everybody if you upgrade to Bionic (18.04, a [Long Term Support release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Current)) now and try to solve the problem there. Also, in the future please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information. It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: **To reviewers:** in the light of OP's own answer it appears that the issue is independent of the specific Ubuntu release. I'll remove its mention from the question and vote to reopen.

Comment: I think it's not a duplicate because the question here is how to do it in the "shell way". In question you've provided here as a duplicate there is no limitation in the way of resolving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `setxkbmap`:

```
setxkbmap -option 'ctrl:nocaps'
```

You can see the list of all available options for `setxkbmap` in this file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`.